# No route matches [GET] "/users/assets/bootstrap.min.js" only in Firefox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, rails-4-2-1

Firefox gives me this error when i try to sign in or sign up into my app, i am only working locally and i am using devise gem for this. After loading the form it cracks into this routing. The file bootstrap.min.js is in the stylesheets folder and into assets folder. In the layouts i have declared:

```
<script src="assets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Chrome and Safari does not have any problem. Another strange behavoir, i guess related to the same issue,  is that when i try to inspect element it falls into this error:

No route matches [GET] "/assets/bootstrap.min.css.map"

The Routes file is done like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :properties
devise_for :users

root "properties#index"

get "about" => "pages#about"

get "user_properties" => "pages#user_properties"

get "contact" => "pages#contact"
```

Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```